# addView() doesn't show a view

Tags: android, view

```
private void showText(){
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
Log.d("MyLog","tags.size="+tags.size());
for (int i=0;i<tags.size();i++){
     Button button = new Button(context);
        button.setText(tags.get(i));
        ll.addView(button, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tagButtons.add(button);
}
}
```

This should be simple but this buttons doesn't show. I checked with logs- tags.size=5 so the problem is not in this. ll is a LinearLayout

Here's layout file :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >



        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/ll2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="TextView" />
                        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

So, it's a very simple code and I don't understand why are theese views are not being added to a layout with id "ll"

Comment: give textview width="wrap_content".

Comment: give scrollview width="match_parent" and height="match_parent"

Answer (score 0):

You should call `invalidate()` on the parent layout which forces children to be drawn on the screen

Answer (score 0):

**Remove the `linearlayout` reference which you have not posted in the question and use like as i have done, *Try this***

- Call `showText()` in `OnCreate`- method If you are using Activities

---

```
private void showText(){ 
    textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
    for (int i=0;i<tags.size();i++){
        Button button = new Button(context);
        button.setText(tags.get(i));
        LinearLayout ll=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);
        ll.addView(button);
    } 
}
```